# Doctrine: undefined index when using the same column for a many to one relation and a composed primary key

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following table structure:

Match (football match)

- id
- date
- ...

Score (one match has many scores)

- Match
- type (half time, finished, penalties)
- value (3:2)

My yml for the score is as follows:

```
id:
    match:
      type: bigint
      associationKey: true
      column: Match
      columnDefinition: bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '@fk/sd_Match/id'
    type:
      type: string
      length: 2
      options:
        fixed: true
```

And the relation:

```
manyToOne:
    match:
      targetEntity: Entity\Match
      inversedBy: scores
      joinColumns:
        Match:
          referencedColumnName: id
```

The problem is, when I do a find, findOneBy... i get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: Match
 /var/www/libe/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Utility/IdentifierFlattener.php:92
 /var/www/libe/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:2501
 /var/www/libe/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/SimpleObjectHydrator.php:144
 /var/www/libe/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/SimpleObjectHydrator.php:69
 /var/www/libe/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/AbstractHydrator.php:147
 /var/www/libe/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Entity/BasicEntityPersister.php:720
 /var/www/libe/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php:196
```

Seems to be a problem when using the same column for both things.

I tried removing Match from the key, the problem then is the score entity doesnt load the Match.

In that case if I do
$score = $scoreRepo->findOneBy(criteria);
$score->getMatch() // returns null, even when in the database there are rows in both tables to build the relation.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have no column named Match. Search problems for uppercase / lowercase

Comment: actually I do. The column in the table is "Match" but the property in the entity is "match". This is an old structure btw